# When I am trying to dragging cell at last index in UITableView getting exception and it is happening for the last index only?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my application,I am performing reordering of cells but I am concatenating selected cells with each other

I have some cells and I am doing some cell animation i.e. user can select any cell and drag to any cell present in my table and after dragging these two cells are replaced by one cell that is created with these two cells.
But my problem is when I am trying to replace the last cell, it is not allowing me to do and the cell which I am trying to drag is added at the bottom without replacing the last cell and it is only happening for last cell

```
Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (50) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (51), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

2013-06-03 15:16:33.636 QuestionPro[6565:1d003] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (50) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (51), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

Here is my code

```
- (void)endedDragGestureWithTranslationPoint:(CGPoint)translation {
[self updateFrameOfDraggedCellForTranlationPoint:translation];

self.draggedCell.layer.shouldRasterize = NO;
[(UITableViewCell *)self.draggedCell setHighlighted:NO animated:YES];

UITableViewCell *oldDraggedCell = [self.draggedCell retain];
NSIndexPath *blankIndexPath = [self.indexPathBelowDraggedCell retain];

CGRect blankCellFrame = oldDraggedCell.frame;
CGPoint blankCellCenter = {
    .x = CGRectGetMidX(blankCellFrame),
    .y = CGRectGetMidY(blankCellFrame)
};

NSIndexPath *rowToMoveTo = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:blankCellCenter];
if ( rowToMoveTo ) {

    CGRect rectForIndexPath = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:rowToMoveTo];
    if (dragGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed ){
        rectForIndexPath = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:self.indexPathBelowDraggedCell];
    }

    NSIndexPath * secIndex = [blankIndexPath copy];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState) animations:^{
        oldDraggedCell.frame = rectForIndexPath;
        [self dragTableViewController:self hideDraggableIndicatorsOfCell:oldDraggedCell];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self dragTableViewController:self removeDraggableIndicatorsFromCell:oldDraggedCell];

        [oldDraggedCell removeFromSuperview];
        [oldDraggedCell release];
    }];

    if (dragGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded && secIndex.row != rowToMoveTo.row ){
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [self joinTableViewCellsAtFirstRow:rowToMoveTo.row andSecondRow:secIndex.row];

        NSArray * delArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:secIndex , nil];
        NSArray * rfrArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:secIndex , nil];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:delArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

        SALTableCellView * toggledCell = (SALTableCellView *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:rowToMoveTo];
        if ( toggledCell.selectedImage && activateDelegate ){
            [activateDelegate spotMarkedWithTitle:toggledCell.title andValue:toggledCell.shownValue andColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        }

        [delArray release];
        [rfrArray release];
        [tableView endUpdates];

        [self recalculateTapSumm];
        [self refreshData];
    }
    else
        hiddenCell.hidden = NO;

    [secIndex release];
    [tableView scrollRectToVisible:rectForIndexPath animated:YES];
}

[blankIndexPath release];
[oldDraggedCell release];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a short answer and a long answer.

Short answer: You can't do what you are doing and i am surprised it works for the other rows.

Long answer: what you are trying to do goes against what a user would "normally" expect to happen. ie. if you "move" a row from one place to another, it would "move" and not combine. As the others have pointed out, the error message says as much. That the number of rows are changing from 51 to 50, as you are deleting the rows. the numbers must be the same when moving rows around.

solution: the solution could be quite simple, although i havent tried it myself. try firing all this delete and update tasks with a slight delay or something. that way, the moving rows would do its thingy and by which time the update task would be ready to remove the row and update the data so that you can show the consolidated row in the destination.

Comment: I had just checked it my NSIndexPath *rowToMoveTo = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:blankCellCenter];
    if ( rowToMoveTo ) {} is not getting called

Comment: blankCellFrame is off the tableview's size?

Comment: so the problem was with the blankCellFrame?

Comment: yes, when I am replacing last cell to selected one it is not replacing, it is just added at last..... sending the URL please check  it http://screencast.com/t/canlu76BC

Comment: I understood the problem in your question, but what did u mean by " if ( rowToMoveTo ) {} is not getting called "?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31104/discussion-between-govi-and-nishi)

Answer (score 0):

Check number of rows before and after you replace the cell.

The error showing you itself says that number of rows before replacing are not equal to the number of rows after replacement.